# Chef recipes not working for Orion

Tags: fiware-orion

Testing Orion Context Broker GE in FIWARE Labs, using a new blueprint template with just orion 0.9.1 software in the tier (tested in centos and ubuntu), it does not work.

After launching a new template instance and entering into the virtual machine:

```
[root@orion63-orion1-1-005760 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
[root@orion63-orion1-1-005760 ~]# chef-client 
Starting Chef Client, version 11.14.6
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["orion-dbcluster::0.8.1_install"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - apt
  - yum
  - orion-dbcluster
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/orion-dbcluster/recipes/0.8.1_install.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/orion-dbcluster/recipes/0.8.1_install.rb:10:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/cache/chef/cookbooks/orion-dbcluster/recipes/0.8.1_install.rb:

  3:  package node[:oriondbcluster][:package_name] do
  4:    version "0.8.1-dev" 
  5:    action :install
  6:  end
  7:  
  8:  shardnode = search(
  9:    :node,
 10>>   "mongodb_cluster_name:#{node['mongodb']['cluster_name']} AND \
 11:     recipes:mongodbshard\\:\\:2.2.3_install  AND \
 12:     chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}" 
 13:  )
 14:  
 15:  
 16:  # context init
 17:  template "/opt/contextini.sh" do
 18:      action :create
 19:      source "contextbroker.init.erb" 

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 4.055387918 seconds
```

Comment: Orion 0.9.1 is a very old version (current version at time of writting this is 0.15.0). Not sure why 0.9.1 stills in the blueprint library... Are there newer versions? Have you tried to deploy them?

Comment: No, there isn't a newer versions. The Orion software component installs this version (or try to install it). How can I check Chef recipes with a newer version? I suppose that with a new version once it is available in the blueprint library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It was an old version. If you want to use the newer version, you should create again the blueprint template with the new orion version. In addition, you can try to execute chef-client in your VM. The older versions should be linked now to the newer ones, to avoid this kind of errors. Sorry for any incovenience